# Center dynamic width elements

Tags: html, css, position, center

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

And here's the markup for that:

```
<section> 
  <h2>Vulputate Tellus Cras Cursus Risus</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="example" id="option_1"> <label for="option_1">Etiam porta sevm</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="example" id="option_2"> <label for="option_2">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="example" id="option_3"> <label for="option_3">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="example" id="option_4"> <label for="option_4">Donec id elit non mi porta</label></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I want to horizontally center the `ul` based on the width of the list items.

The gray highlighted item is the hover state of an item.

The parent container has a fixed width/height.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you need to change your input types to "checkbox." And change the section tag to a div (e.g. div id="container")

Then set a width and margin (0px auto) for the ul or container.

For the highlight, set (in the css) `li:hover {background-color:#ddd;}`

I'm not sure what you mean by "The parent container has a fixed width/height." But if you specify more I'd be glad to help.

End result:

```
<style>ul{padding:0;} li{list-style-type:none; display:block;} #section{width:364px; margin:auto;} ul{} li:hover{background-color:#ddd;} input{}</style>

<div id="section"> 
  <h2>Vulputate Tellus Cras Cursus Risus</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="example" id="option_1"> <label for="option_1">Etiam porta sevm</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="example" id="option_2"> <label for="option_2">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="example" id="option_3"> <label for="option_3">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="example" id="option_4"> <label for="option_4">Donec id elit non mi porta</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

test [here](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) by copy and pasting

And would you like the code to make the checkboxes those images? And is the font Arial? How accurate do you want it to that photo?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify a width for your `ul` in CSS to do that:

```
ul{
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}
```